# How can I get the result data from vertex shader transformations back to the CPU?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm learning OpenGl and have the following scenario,

- I have multiple 2D circles moving randomly in a grid.
- The lines of the circles sometimes intercept the lines of the grid.
- I would like to do something where the intersection of the geometries occur, i.e. at the point of intersection between the lines of the circle and the lines of the grid.

My problem is the following, I'm making the transformation calculations for the circles movement in the vertex shader, how could I get the result data from the transformations back to the main program to calculate the intersection point I need?

And more generally, what's the best way to work with shaders? I could do all the transformations on the CPU, calculate the intersection points I need, and send the final points to the shaders, but wouldn't that be wasting the capabilities of the GPU? I understand the GPU is good at precisely this kind of operations.

Comment: For something like this, you shouldn't try to get back transformation data. Moving a circle is pretty trivial, as is doing intersection tests with a circle and a grid. There's no point in doing a full CPU->GPU->CPU round trip when the CPU is perfectly capable of doing that computation on its own.

Comment: If you end up with more complicated things that you really want to do on the GPU, OpenCL is probably you're best bet.